# 'AutoFilter Method of Range class failed' when changing from Form Control to ActiveX

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, autofilter

I am using Excel 2013 and put a Form Control DropDown/ComboBox with this code attached:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim Issuer As String
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Data")
Issuer = ws1.Range("IssuerNum").Value

If Issuer = "All" Then
    ws1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    LastRow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    FirstRow = ws1.Cells(2, 1).Row
Else
    ws1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, Criteria1:=Issuer, Operator:=xlFilterValues

    With ws1.ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
         LastRow = .Areas(.Areas.Count).Row + .Areas(.Areas.Count).Rows.Count - 1
    End With
    FirstRow =   ws1.ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 2).Row

End If
```

Previously, I had the same code in a Form Control on the sheet where I was filtering the data. Whatever value is chosen in the dropdown is what drives the filter. Everything worked perfectly. Then, I decided that I wanted to use an ActiveX control ComboBox and added this code into the ComboBox change sub on a separate worksheet (Dashboard) where the new ComboBox was now located. Whenever I choose the value, I get the *AutoFilter Method of Range class failed*.

Comment: Is it a form control or ActiveX control? You mention both. Which line of code is it,."Issuer"?

Comment: The code above is in an ActiveX control. I was using the same code on a different worksheet that was a form control and it was working fine. Moving the worksheet and changing the control is where the error began.

Comment: Also, the code is breaking at "ws1.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter _
        Field:=1, Criteria1:=Issuer, Operator:=xlFilterValues"